# How to create custom button component in angular 2+ versions. using ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular

How to create custom button component in angular 2+ versions. using ControlValueAccessor.
How to handle click button and focus events in custom button.

Below is sample code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, Input, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'cubutton',
  templateUrl: './rmbutton.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rmbutton.component.css'],
   providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => RmbuttonComponent),
      multi: true
    }]
})
export class CubuttonComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() disabled = false;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() buttonname;
  @Input() iconstyle:string;
  @Input() class:string;
  @Input() id: string;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  writeValue(value: any) {}

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {}

  registerOnTouched() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using @HostListener('click')?